# Laravel Relationships Conditions - 3 tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've got a situation where I've got Posts, Users and Comments.

Each comment stores a post_id and a user_id. What I want to do is get all of a user's comments on a particular post, so that I can do a call like this:

```
$comments = Auth::User()->comments(post_id=x)->text
```

(where I know what x is)

I have:

```
User->HasMany(comments)
Comments->HasOne(User)
Comments->HasOne(Project)
Project->HasMany(comments)
```

I feel like there needs to be a where or a has or a wherehas or something thrown in.. the best I can manage is that I pull Auth::User()->comments into an array and then search through the array until I find the matching post ID.. that seems wasteful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with` doesn't apply any join, so you can't reference other table.

You can use this:

```
// User model
public function comments()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Comment');
}

// Comment model
public function scopeForPost($query, $postId)
{
  $query->where('post_id', $postId);
}

// then you can do this:
Auth::user()->comments()->forPost($postId)->get();
```

Alternatively you can eager load comments with constraint:

```
User::with(['comments' => function ($q) use ($postId) {
   $q->where('post_id', $postId);
}])->find($someUserId);

// or exactly the same as above, but for already fetched user:
// $user .. or
Auth::user()->load(['comments' => function ($q) use ($postId) {
   $q->where('post_id', $postId);
}]);

// then you can access comments for $postId just like this:
Auth::user()->comments; // collection
```

Comment: You are right... Join was not being applied in my example....+1 for providing correct solution :)

Comment: The scopeforPost method is beautiful, thank you. Exactly what I was after. Definitely points me in the right direction for other things, too.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to filter your relations, you just have to do it in your Eloquent query:

```
$data = User::with('posts', 'comments')
          ->where('users.id', Auth::User()->id)
          ->where('posts.id', $postID)
          ->get();
```

Then you can

```
foreach($data->comments as $comment)
{
   echo $comment->text;
}
```

Comment: I have a same problem...I used the code $data = Event::with('section','programs')->where('event_id', '1')->where('section_id','3')->get(); But i am getting an mysql error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'section_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tblEvent` where `event_id` = 1 and `section_id` = 3)"

Comment: It seems that join is not being applied properly. Please suggest

Comment: You probably need to reference the table where that column is coming from, example: `where('sections.event_id', '1')`, but it also looks like a join is missing, so you'll have to check your Eloquent relations.

Comment: I have added relations in related models

Comment: Can you please discuss this in chat room.. and send me a link of chat?

Comment: You don't reference related tables when using `with`. Joins are needed if you want to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Your Comments table would have foreign keys Post_Id and User_ID

To Access all the comments of a particular post from a particular user , can you try this way?

```
Comment::select('comments.*')
                        ->where('comments.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                        ->leftJoin('posts','posts.id','=','comments.post_id')
                        ->leftJoin('users','users.id','=','comments.user_id')
                        ->get();
```

Am sure there is better way to achieve it, but this should give you desired results.

**Note** use aliases if you have conflicting column names

Let me know if this worked.